# Reversing x-axis only for some sub-plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with the dada2 package in R, which has a function called `plotQualityProfile()` which makes some calculations and calls `ggplot()` to make a graph. The part that calls `ggplot()` looks like this:

```R
    p <- ggplot(data = plotdf, aes(x = Cycle, y = Score)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = Count)) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F5F5F5", 
      high = "black") + geom_line(data = statdf, aes(y = Mean), 
      color = "#66C2A5") + geom_line(data = statdf, aes(y = Q25), 
      color = "#FC8D62", linewidth = 0.25, linetype = "dashed") + 
      geom_line(data = statdf, aes(y = Q50), color = "#FC8D62", 
        linewidth = 0.25) + geom_line(data = statdf, 
      aes(y = Q75), color = "#FC8D62", linewidth = 0.25, 
      linetype = "dashed") + ylab("Quality Score") + xlab("Cycle") + 
      theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
      guides(fill = "none") + geom_text(data = anndf, 
      aes(x = 0, label = rclabel, y = 0), color = "red", 
      hjust = 0) + facet_wrap(~file)
```

When I use it, I can pass on arguments to `ggplot()` like usual, this will for example produce the graph below from my data:

```R
plotQualityProfile(paths_to_data_files) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = "none"))
```

[QualityProfile.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKXsx.png)

The only thing I want to change is to reverse the x-axis for every second column of sub-plots (i.e. every second sample of the input). I could do:

```R
plotQualityProfile(paths_to_data_files) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = "none") +
  scale_x_reverse())
```

...but that reverses the x-axis for all sub-plots. Is there some way giving arguments to `scale_x_reverse()` to tell it which specific sub-plots or columns to act upon? Or is there another way? As the `ggplot()` call is embedded into the `plotQualityProfile()` function, I need to be able to do this with only one `ggplot()` call.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might have a look at `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` which allows to individually set the positional scales per panel. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.